# FATAL DBT-10317 Specified SID Name already exists

Tags: oracle

I was creating a new instance in Oracle 12c Database and it got interrupted due to internet connectivity.
Again I ran the command dbca -silent -createDatabase -responseFile /u01/app/soft/database_sw_12201/response/dbca.rsp but it gave error.
[FATAL] [DBT-10317] Specified SID Name (TRAX) already exists.
ACTION: Specify a different SID Name that does not already exist.

I check /etc/oratab and inventory.xml files both and it does not have the SID name.
'
What could be the problem? Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the response logs. Also try DBCA GUI and check if SID exists and then try to drop the DB.

Answer (score 0):

After an interrupted installation remove any mention of the SID from :

- /etc/oratab
- ${ORACLE_BASE}/oraInventory/ContentsXML/inventory.xml

Additionally make sure no processes are left running and clean up lingering shared memory segment by either rebooting the server or doing :

> ipcs -a

then:

> ipcrm -m {shmid}
>
> ipcrm -m {semid}

for every shared memory segment and semaphore that exists for your Oracle user.